# Как можно сделать такое на jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

[Вот](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index.html)

Хочу сделать такое, но на `jQuery`. Я делаю через `Show/Hide`, но при этом он как бы начинается с левого верхнего угла и достигает нижнего правого. Но как сделать, как на ссылке сделано? Т.е, он начал с верхнего левого угла и переместился на 20 пикселей через диагональ и остановился, появился, но с помощью Show.

Comment: [``.animate()``](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

Comment: я использовал animate() до этого, но я хочу эффект Show получить. Чтобы постепенно он появлялся. Грубую форму с animate() я сделал. А щас хочу чтобы появлялся постепенно.

Comment: @navi1893, вы даже не осилили дочитать страницу документации до примера?

> To animate the opacity, left offset, and height of the image simultaneously:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать animate - это же очевидно

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/6z56W/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через css3 анимацию. Она более плавная и жрет меньше системных ресурсов. 
[Вот](http://jsbin.com/uwuped/2/edit)